how to reference complete details of one table to another table in mysql
I want to reference The details of the respective resident from resident table to companion table. can someone tell me how to do that?
CREATE TABLE EMPLOYEE
(
name varchar(20),
addrs varchar(30),
e_adharno bigint CHECK (e_adharno BETWEEN 100000000000 AND 999999999999) primary key,
e_mobno bigint CHECK (e_mobno BETWEEN 1000000000 AND 9999999999),
e_email varchar(20),
dof_join date,
salary int
);
CREATE TABLE RESIDENT
(
name varchar(20),
addrs varchar(30),
r_adharno bigint CHECK (r_adharno BETWEEN 100000000000 AND 999999999999) primary key,
gender varchar(10),
age int,
r_mobno bigint CHECK (r_mobno BETWEEN 1000000000 AND 9999999999),
r_email varchar(20)
);
CREATE TABLE COMPANION
(
name varchar(20),
gender varchar(10),
c_mobno bigint CHECK (c_mobno BETWEEN 1000000000 AND 9999999999),
);



https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization

Too strange structure. Does the employee have no a gender whereas the companion have it?
